# How to setup a ChildHtml Block/Code

Tags: coding

I have a phtml file that displays/echo's a block of HTML code that I wish to place onto the product page of my website.

basically, I'd like to add this piece of code to the view.phtml:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_categories');
```

The fileself resides in catalog/product/categories.phtml - and needs to access `$this->getProduct();` in order to do it's "coding".

I understand that my phtml file needs to reside inside of the skin that I created - and I have done that.  How can I setup/tell magento that 'my_data' is a block or phtml file that resides in where I put it, so that it get's executed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you could add your block as a child of the block `product.info.additional` and then you would not have to change any templates as this block will get the html of all it's children.

Normally also the block that you are using on a product page is often of type `catalog/product_view`. This will allow you to get the current product and use other common functions to do with product view.

Comment: Thank you.  The catalog/product_view was the last piece of the puzzle and solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

add your phtml  file in `app/design/frontend/theme/catalog/product` folder or `app/design/frontend/default/default/catalog/product` folder.

Then you have to add the below code
`<block type="core/template" name="product.mydata" as="media" template="catalog/product/my_data.phtml"/>` under the handle tag  in layout/catalog.xml

Comment: when my phtml calls `$this->getProduct();` it returns a no object?  Any idea how I should fix that?

Comment: I tried to upvote you both - but it would not let me. :(